# jquery slideToggle on all open div s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have div s with id like that:
manufacturer_12,
manufacturer_37,
manufacturer_71,
etc...

is there a way to find all the div s which their visibility is visible, and to do to them something like:

```
$('[id^="manufacturer"]').slideToggle("slow");
```

the problem is that its imposibble to make a for loop because their id isn't consecutive.

maybe i should use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ ?

Comment: Did you try your code ? It gets your divs, you just have to add `:visible` to get only visible ones.

Comment: Do you want them to slide up all at once or one after the other?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.each`, but this may work:

```
$("[id^='manufacturer']:visible").slideToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

```
$('[id^="manufacturer"]').filter(":visible").slideToggle("slow");
```

But be aware that [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) will apply to all matched elements as the documentation says. So, you actually don't need to use `.each()` here.

> `.slideToggle( [duration] [, callback] )`
>
> Returns: jQuery
>
> Description: Display or hide the **matched elements** with a sliding motion.

In this case, all visible elements with `id` starting with `manufacturer`.

Answer (score 1):

Believe me, that's not a good way of doing things. 
You'd better assign a specific class to all items of interest and write a very simple selector basing on class name only. This will work much faster.